# Join three tables on a common column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having three tables named Table1, Table2 and Table3. Table1 is having Columns (mobNum bigint, visitedUS DateTime). Table2 is having Columns (mobNum bigint, visitedUK DateTime). Table3 is having Columns (mobNum bigint, visitedChina DateTime).  Sample data is as follows

Table1

```
___________________________       
    mobnum | visitedUS
___________________________ 
9000000001 |  20/10/18  
___________________________ 
9000000001 | 11/07/19  
___________________________ 
9000000002 | 01/02/17
___________________________
```

Table2

```
    mobnum | visitedUK
___________________________ 
9000000001 | 03/05/19  
___________________________ 
9000000002 |10/10/18  
___________________________
```

Table3

```
    mobnum | visitedChina
___________________________ 
9000000001 | 15/03/18 
___________________________
```

Now I want SQL query to show result like below

```
              Result Table
   -------------------------------------------------------
   mobnum      | visitedUS    | visitedUK  | visitedChina  
   -------------------------------------------------------
     9000000001|20/10/18      |  03/05/19  |  15/03/18    
   -------------------------------------------------------
     9000000001|11/07/19      |  Null      |   Null       
   -------------------------------------------------------
     9000000002|01/02/17      | 10/10/18   |   Null       
   -------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: did one of the answers resolve the issue for you?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't test or double check spelling/syntax:

```
select 
    isnull(t1.mobnum,isnull(t2.mobnum,t3.mobnum)) mobnum,
    t1.visitedUS, 
    t2.visitedUK, 
    t3.visitedChina
from Table1 t1
full outer join Table2 t2 on t1.mobnum = t2.mobnum
full outer join Table3 t3 on t3.mobnum = isnull(t1.mobnum,t2.mobnum)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [mobnum] [bigint] NULL,
    [visitedUS] [date] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table2](
    [mobnum] [bigint] NULL,
    [visitedUK] [date] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table3](
    [mobnum] [bigint] NULL,
    [visitedChina] [date] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([mobnum], [visitedUS]) VALUES (9000000001, CAST(N'2018-10-20' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([mobnum], [visitedUS]) VALUES (9000000002, CAST(N'2018-10-30' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([mobnum], [visitedUK]) VALUES (9000000001, CAST(N'2018-11-10' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([mobnum], [visitedUK]) VALUES (9000000003, CAST(N'2018-11-25' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table3] ([mobnum], [visitedChina]) VALUES (9000000001, CAST(N'2018-12-01' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Table3] ([mobnum], [visitedChina]) VALUES (9000000004, CAST(N'2018-12-10' AS Date))
GO
```

now check with following query

```
SELECT ISNULL(t1.mobnum, ISNULL(t2.mobnum, t3.mobnum)) mobnum,
       t1.visitedUS,
       t2.visitedUK,
       t3.visitedChina
FROM Table1 t1
    FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 t2
        ON t1.mobnum = t2.mobnum
    FULL OUTER JOIN Table3 t3
        ON t3.mobnum = ISNULL(t1.mobnum, t2.mobnum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just my 2 cents, a solution with a more clean solution is to use colesce instead of multiple ISNULLs:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.mobnum, t2.mobnum, t3.mobnum) mobnum,
       t1.visitedUS,
       t2.visitedUK,
       t3.visitedChina
FROM Table1 t1
    FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.mobnum = t2.mobnum
    FULL OUTER JOIN Table3 t3 ON t3.mobnum = ISNULL(t1.mobnum, t2.mobnum);
```

Comment: I didn't know that about coalesce.  It is much cleaner.  I would suggest using it in the join statement also just for consistency/similarity.

Answer (score 0):

`FULL OUTER JOIN` is going to create fun result sets when you have multiple rows in each table.  The better way to solve this uses `union all`, `row_number()` and `group by`:

```
select mobnum,
       max(visitedUS) as visitedUS,
       max(visitedUK) as visitedUK,
       max(visitedChina) as visitedChina
from ((select mobnum, visitedUS, null as visitedUS, null as visitedChina,
              row_number() over (partition by mobnum order by visitedUS) as seqnum
       from table1
      ) union all
      (select mobnum, null as visitedUS, visitedUK, null as visitedChina,
              row_number() over (partition by mobnum order by visitedUK) as seqnum
       from table2
      ) union all
      (select mobnum, null as visitedUS, null as visitedUK, visitedChina,
              row_number() over (partition by mobnum order by visitedChina) as seqnum
       from table1
      )
     ) v
group by mobnum, seqnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with table1rn(mobnum, visitedUS, rn) as
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by mobnum order by visitedUS) rn
from table1
),
table2rn(mobnum, visitedUK, rn) as
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by mobnum order by visitedUK) rn
from table2
),
table3rn(mobnum, visitedChina, rn) as
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by mobnum order by visitedChina) rn
from table3
)
select t1.mobnum, t1.visitedUS, t2.visitedUK, t3.visitedChina
from table1rn t1
left join table2rn t2 on t2.mobnum = t1.mobnum and t2.rn = t1.rn
left join table3rn t3 on t3.mobnum = t1.mobnum and t3.rn = t1.rn
```